# urlpatterns not behaving as expected

Tags: django, django-urls

I have specified a url to list students and a url to display the student details however the url for the student details doesnt seem to work.

The ursl.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('create/', views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/',views.SchoolUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete'),
    path('students', views.StudentListView.as_view(), name='student_list'),
    path('students/<int:pk>/',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_details'),
]
```

but when I click on the actual student it doesnt take me to basic_app/students/1 (for example) but to basic_app/1

Also when I manually type /basic_app/students/1 I get an error which says:

```
NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/students/1/
Reverse for 'update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['basic_app/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

[no reverse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2BUw.png)

my views:

```
class StudentListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'students'
    model = models.Student

class StudentDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'student_details'
    model = models.Student
    template_name = 'basic_app/student_detail.html'
```

the model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("basic_app:student_details",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

The student_details.html template:

```
{% extends 'basic_app/basic_app_base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container jumbotron">

  <h2>Student Details:</h2>
  <p>Name: {{student_details.name}}</p>
  <p>Principal: {{student_details.age}}</p>
  <p>Location: {{student_details.school}}</p>


<!-- <div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_details.pk %}">Update</a>
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'basic_app:delete' pk=school_details.pk %}">Delete</a>
  <a href="{% url 'basic_app:list' %}">Cancel</a>
</div> -->
{%  endblock %}
```

What have I done wrong?`

Comment: If you look at `path('', views.IndexView.as_view()),` and `path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),` they point to the same url, but use a different view?

Comment: sorry that was a typo i introduced I corrected it

Comment: can you add `basic_app/student_detail.html` template?

Comment: I just added the basic_app/student_detail.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commented-out section in your student_details.html may be producing the error. Delete that part and it should work:

```
{% extends 'basic_app/basic_app_base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container jumbotron">

  <h2>Student Details:</h2>
  <p>Name: {{student_details.name}}</p>
  <p>Principal: {{student_details.age}}</p>
  <p>Location: {{student_details.school}}</p>
{%  endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks! that commented out code was stopping it from working.  I dont know how to get the student links to work though.

Comment: I fixed the other issue on the student link taking me to the wrong url. My href was incorrect on the student_list page.